# virtualenv doesn't work on git bash MINGW32

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I'm a git newbie.
I'm working on Windows and I use Git Bash MINGW32.
I was working in my directory on master Branch
in "env" environmental (created by myself with virtualenv).
For an error I close my shell and now I cannot reactivate env environemntal.
I try with

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

but i cannot see env in the prompt.
I try to create another virtual environmental using

```
VIRTUALENV env1
```

and then

```
env1\Scripts\activate
```

But i don't see env1 in the prompt.

If I create a test virtual environmental using msdos prompt it works.

Any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you rather try sourcing the environment (*after* `VIRTUALENV env1`, provided your virtualenv is 1.7.1+):

```
. env/Scripts/activate
or
source env/Scripts/activate
```

In a bash session, you would use `/` or (Windows bash) `\\`

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but i have the same problem as OP, and this does not work for me either. It I use the cmd shell of windows it works fine. Ideas?

Comment: @ToaoG that answer is valid when you are using the git bash shell (which you can call in windows with `git-bash.bat` within the msysgit "Git for Windows" distribution. It wouldn't work with `git-cmd.bat` cmd shell session.

Comment: You may need forward slashes.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly.